# How to use strerror_l with current locale?

Tags: c, linux, posix, libc, strerror

I'm fixing some Linux code which used `strerror` (not thread-safe) for multi-threading. I found that `strerror_r` and `strerror_l` are both thread-safe. Due to different definitions for `strerror_r` (depending on `_GNU_SOURCE` it is differently defined) I'd like to use the newer `strerror_l` function, but how am I supposed to obtain a `locale_t` object for the current locale? I'm not using `iconv` or anything, just plain libc, and I don't see how I can obtain a "default locale" object (I don't care in what language the error is printed, I just want a human readable string.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass "" to the locale parameter newlocale will allocate a locale object set to the current native locale[1]

[1]http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/newlocale.html

```
static  locale_t locale;

bool MyStrerrorInit(void)
{
    locale = newlocale(LC_ALL_MASK,"",(locale_t)0);
    
    if (locale == (locale_t)0) {
       return false;
    }
 
    return true;
}
    
char * MyStrerror(int error)
{
    return strerror_l(error, locale);
}
```

Comment: You can use LC_ALL_MASK instead of ORing all of the category masks

Answer (score 4):

You could use [POSIX `uselocale`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/uselocale.html):

```c
strerror_l(errno, uselocale((locate_t)0));
```

---

@TavianBarnes pointed out in the comment that this code can exhibit undefined behavior:

> [CX] [Option Start] The behavior is undefined if the locale argument to strerror_l() is the special locale object LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE or is not a valid locale object handle. [Option End]

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strerror.html

> Upon successful completion, the uselocale() function shall return a handle for the thread-local locale that was in use as the current locale for the calling thread on entry to the function, or LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE if no thread-local locale was in use.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/uselocale.html

[Use of LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE with *_l() functions](https://austin-group-l.opengroup.narkive.com/MFGftIBP/use-of-lc-global-locale-with-l-functions)  clarified the UB behavior of `*_l()` functions when given `LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE` as the `locale`, provided a version without undefined behavior and discussed alternatives.

An obvious version that isn't thread safe:

```
locale_t locale = uselocale((locate_t)0);

if (locale == LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE) {
  strerror(errno);
} else {
  strerror_l(errno, locale);
}
```

A thread-safe version:

```
locale_t locale = uselocale((locate_t)0);
locale_t copy = loc;

if (copy == LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE) {
  copy = duplocale(copy);
}

strerror_l(errno, copy);

if (loc == LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE) {
  freelocale(copy);
}
```

Here's [a full working example](https://github.com/tavianator/bfs/blob/70fe3b12852ca7fb5bf1529042754fc75e69baa0/src/bfstd.c#L280) from @TavianBarnes.

Comment: Well, technically, `NULL` is odd here. It's not `NULL`, it's `(locale_t)0`. `uselocale((locale_t)0)`. Is `locale_t` guaranteed to be a pointer?

Comment: @KamilCuk You're right, I mixed `uselocale` up with `setlocale`. I don't think `locale_t` is guaranteed to be a pointer, except that it is in glibc. I've incorporated this into my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I upvoted this answer but then noticed a problem: uselocale() [shall return ... LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE if no thread-local locale was in use](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/uselocale.html), but [the behavior is undefined if the locale argument to strerror_l() is the special locale object LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strerror.html).

Comment: TIL about this UB. Thanks @TavianBarnes, I've incorporated your comment into my answer :)

Comment: If the point is to be thread safe then you can't call `strerror(errno)` in the `LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE` case.  What you can do is `duplocale()` and then pass it to `strerror_l()`.  Full working example: https://github.com/tavianator/bfs/blob/70fe3b12852ca7fb5bf1529042754fc75e69baa0/src/bfstd.c#L280

Comment: I misread "since an implementation may have extensions with new categories
there should be a way to dup a locale and make modifications
without specific mention of those extensions, otherwise a supposedly
portable library could end up clobbering any extensions in the duped locale" at https://austin-group-l.opengroup.narkive.com/MFGftIBP/use-of-lc-global-locale-with-l-functions#post6 to mean that duplocale wouldn't work. Are there scenarios where duplocale won't work? What are they?

Comment: @DanielLe I believe the "clobbering any extensions in the duped locale" complaint was about the `setlocale() + newlocale() + setlocale() + ...` approach.  That discussion led to this POSIX issue which defined the behaviour of `duplocale(LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE)`: https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=301